# Autosubmit Hierarchical select

Tags: 7, forms, taxonomy-terms

I'm building a custom block that shows Hierarchical select form , I'm trying to autosubmit it after make a selection I'm using this code :

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {



      $(".hierarchical-select-wrapper").bind("change-hierarchical-select",function(){
        console.log("Yes changed hierarchical-select");
        jQuery("#location-selector-form").submit();
        //$("#location-selector-form .form-submit").trigger("click");
      })


    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

My form is autosubmited but with no values (I checked this with `dpm($form_state);` )